# how can I count the number of layer of 3D array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, count

If 3D `array` `a` is defined as below,

```
a <- rep(NA,200)
a <- array(data = a, dim = c(10,10,2))
```

`a` consists of 2 layers of a 10 (column)*10 (row) matrix.
I know that I can use `ncol` or `nrow` for counting column and row of each layer of `a`. in this case I can simply count manually the number of layers of `a`,  because it has just 2 layers of data; but for the case when the number of layers `a` is much larger (such as 200 or 2000, not just 2), then I cannot count manually how many layers `a` has.

So I wonder if there is a function which counts the number of layers of a 3D `array` in R.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can check `dim(a)`

Comment: oh, there was such a simple answer!!!
it was what I've been looking for.
thank you so much.

Comment: even though it was too simple and silly question, I had failed to find the function through the net.thank you, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

We use `dim` to find the dimensions.

```
dim(a)
```

According to `?dim`

> ```
> For an array (and hence in particular, for a matrix) ‘dim’
>  retrieves the ‘dim’ attribute of the object.  It is ‘NULL’ or a
>  vector of mode ‘integer’.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that there was a voting system, too.